# git clone issues via an SSH proxied host

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

I have a setup where we are using a bastion/jump-host to access a remote server and I'm having issues doing my git clone.

In my git config i have the followings setup:

#### Local  .ssh/config

```
Host *.remotedomain.org
   ProxyCommand ssh -l username jumphost nc %h 22`
   LogLevel DEBUG1
```

#### Remote .ssh/config

```
LogLevel DEBUG1
```

So if I do `ssh remoteDevel.remotedomain.org` it will route me via this proxy host and all is good.

#### Case 1 - Clone on the Remote side

```
#Log into remote machine via SSH
ssh remoteDevel

#Clone repo
git clone ssh://git@stash.remotedomain.org:7999/mirror/disjockey.git
```

What I noticed is the SSH debug "stuff" prints out this line

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/USER/disjockey/.git/
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p 7999 stash.remotedomain.org
```

This looks like to me like its making a proxy into the Atlassian Stash server to pull down the git repo (good)

#### Case 2 - Local via Proxy

When I try the same command locally things go awry

```
git clone ssh://git@stash.remotedomain.org:7999/mirror/disjockey.git
```

First I see it tries to go via the jumpiest

```
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -l USERNAME jumphost nc stash.remotedomain.org 22
....
#Lots of junk
....
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@stash.remotedomain.org's password:
```

#### So?

Well obviously it isn't working as I hoped.  From what I can tell my proxy command is likely off as it looks like its trying to proxy into `stash:22` when I run it locally and into `stash:7999` when I run it remotely.

I tried to change my proxy command to:

`ProxyCommand ssh -l username jumphost nc %h 7999`

But that seems to never log in correctly.  Not exactly sure what to do here but I'm assuming its probably something simple that I'm missing?

#### Updates SocksProxy

I found a way to make things work - but I'm confused as to how this actually helps things

First I create a Socks Proxy with : `ssh -D 1080 machine.remotedomain.org`

Then I edit my `.ssh/config`

```
#Host *.remotedomain.org
#   ProxyCommand ssh -l username jumphost nc %h 22`
#   LogLevel DEBUG1

Host stash.remotedomain.org
    User git
    ProxyCommand nc -x localhost:1080 %h %p
```

And then my `git clone` will work, however, this is problematic because i had to comment out the lines i needed in the 1st place to create my socks tunnel.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `%p` in the ProxyCommand instead of hardcoding the port number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We got things working!  Here was the `.ssh/config` that did the trick.

Host **remote** connects to the machine `gen1` on the remote network.

Connecting to:  **stash.remotedomain.org** basically does a 2nd proxy on top of the **remote** one, and proxies into port `7999` which is what the git server (atlassian stash) is running.

```
Host remote
    HostName gen1
    ProxyCommand ssh -l username jumphost nc %h %p

Host stash.remotedomain.org
    ProxyCommand ssh remote nc stash 7999
```

So when I do:  `git clone ssh://git@stash.remotedomain.org:7999/mirror/disjockey.git`
everything works!!